# ViewController not calling deinit method swift 4

Tags: iphone, swift, ios11, swift4

I have this VC where I play a video background login. 
the two buttons as outlets trigger a UIStoryboard Push Segue directly from storyboard.

what I want to achieve is: once I go to any of the of the VC through the segues the video login VC deinits to avoid further retaining cycles once I go back to this with the normal flow of my app.

thanks in advance.

```
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var registerButton: UIButton!
weak var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
weak var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.loginButton = Util.roundBorderButton(button: self.loginButton, color: UIColor.white.cgColor, radius: 5, width: 1)
    self.registerButton = Util.roundBorderButton(button: self.registerButton, color: UIColor.white.cgColor, radius: 5, width: 1)

    if let resourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "porsche-trimmed", withExtension: "mp4") {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: resourceUrl.path) {

            avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: resourceUrl)
            avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
            avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            avPlayer.volume = 0
            avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

            avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.backgroundColor = .clear
            view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: avPlayer.currentItem)
        }
    }
}

@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
    let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    p.seek(to: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler: nil)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    avPlayer.play()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

deinit {
    print("deinit video")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: "to avoid further retaining cycles"  Que!?  How does calling deinit lead to avoidance of retaining cycles?  If you say "further," where does it occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1:

Try writing `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` line in `override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`.
May be notification center retaining you viewController's object.

Case 2: 
If you are navigating from you controller using Segue then `UIStoryboardSegue` retaining you viewController's object as source viewController.
In that case too first case can solve you issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the notification center retains your controller? Try commenting out the notification subscription and see if the problem goes away. If it does, choose some appropriate place (viewWillDisappear?) to unsubscribe.